# Collate data from multiple workbooks to a separate workbook based on column names

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple workbooks in a folder and i need to copy paste data from some of them based on naming convention. I am copy pasting data based on column names to a master sheet as order of columns in source files is not the same. Code pasted below does the task but it looks for exact match in column names and as a result i am only able to capture 80% of the data as few column names in source files are not an exact match. For eg: A column in the **Target file** with header **Premium** is mentioned as **Premium @ 25%** in the **Source file**. This is just an example.

```
            Sub ImportExcelfiles()
               Dim strPath As String
               Dim strFile As String
               Dim wbSource As Workbook
               Dim wsSource As Worksheet
               Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
               Dim bookName As Worksheet
               
               Dim rowCountSource As Long
               Dim colCountSource As Long
               Dim rowOutputTarget As Long
               Dim colOutputTarget As Long
               
               Dim found1 As Range, found2 As Range, j As Long, Cr1 As String, srcRow As Range
               
               'Variables for Sheet - Workbook Name
               Dim nameCount As Long
               Dim fileName As String
               
              Application.DisplayAlerts = False
              Application.ScreenUpdating = False
              
               '====================================
               'SET THE PATH AND FILE TO THE FOLDER
               '====================================
               
               strPath = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Control").Range("C4")
               fileName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Control").Range("C5")
               
               If Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then strPath = strPath & "\"
             
              
               'set the target worksheet
               Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Data")
               Set bookName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Workbook Name")
               
              
               'set the initial output row and column count for master data and workbook name
                  nameCount = 2
                  rowOutputTarget = wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
               
               'get the first file
               strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xlsx*")
              
               'loop throught the excel files in the folder
               Do While strFile <> ""
                  
                  If InStr(strFile, fileName) > 0 Then
            
                     'open the workbook
                     Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strFile)
                     Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("Details")
                   
              
                     'get the row and column counts
                    With wsSource
                        colCountSource = .Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                        For j = 1 To colCountSource
                            Cr1 = .Cells(2, j).Value
                            Set srcRow = .Range("A2", .Cells(1, colCountSource))
                            Set found1 = srcRow.Find(What:=Cr1, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
                    
                            If Not found1 Is Nothing Then
                                colCountSource = wsTarget.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                        
                                Set srcRow = wsTarget.Range("A1", wsTarget.Cells(1, colCountSource))
                                Set found2 = srcRow.Find(What:=Cr1, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=F)
            
                                If Not found2 Is Nothing Then
                                    rowCountSource = .Cells(Rows.Count, found1.Column).End(xlUp).Row
                                    .Range(.Cells(3, found1.Column), .Cells(rowCountSource, found1.Column)).Copy
                                    found2.Offset(rowOutputTarget, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                            
                                End If
                            End If
                        Next j
                    End With
            
                    bookName.Range("A" & nameCount).Value = wbSource.Name
                    'update output row  '2+12-1=13
                     
                    nameCount = nameCount + 1
                    rowOutputTarget = rowOutputTarget + rowCountSource - 2
                    
                    'close the opened workbook
                    wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
                  End If
                  'get the next file
                  strFile = Dir()
               Loop
               
                Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                
                MsgBox "Data imported.", vbInformation
            End Sub
```

This code takes approximately 5 mins to copy paste data. Is there a way to optimise it and also solve my problem of missing 20% data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the target column name is the shorter you need to search the source column names for each target column name.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ImportExcelfiles()

    Dim strPath As String, strFile As String, fileName As String
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim bookName As Worksheet
   
    Dim rowCountSource As Long, colCountSource As Long
    Dim colCountTarget As Long
    Dim rowOutputTarget As Long, colOutputTarget As Long
   
    Dim found1 As Range, found2 As Range, j As Long
    Dim Cr1 As String, srcRow As Range
   
    'Variables for Sheet - Workbook Name
    Dim nameCount As Long
    Dim t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
       
    strPath = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Control").Range("C4")
    If Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then strPath = strPath & "\"
    fileName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Control").Range("C5")

    'set the target worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wsTarget = .Sheets("Master Data")
        Set bookName = .Sheets("Workbook Name")
    End With
   
   'set the initial output row and column count
   'for master data and workbook name
    nameCount = 2
    Dim arTarget, rngSrc As Range, rngTarget As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long, n As Long
    With wsTarget
        rowOutputTarget = 1 + .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ' array of target column names
        colCountTarget = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        arTarget = .Cells(1, 1).Resize(, colCountTarget)
    End With
   'get the first file
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xlsx*")
  
    'loop throught the excel files in the folder
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While strFile <> ""
      
        If InStr(strFile, fileName) > 0 Then

            'open the workbook
            Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strFile, ReadOnly:=True)
            Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("Details")
           
            With wsSource
                'get the row and column counts'get the row and column counts
                colCountSource = .Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                Set srcRow = .Range("A2", .Cells(1, colCountSource))
                ' loop through target columns
                For j = 1 To UBound(arTarget, 2)
                    Cr1 = arTarget(1, j)
                    Set found1 = srcRow.Find(What:=Cr1, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=True)
                    ' found
                    If Not found1 Is Nothing Then
                        rowCountSource = .Cells(.Rows.Count, found1.Column).End(xlUp).Row
                        n = rowCountSource - 2
                        Set rngSrc = .Range(.Cells(3, found1.Column), .Cells(rowCountSource, found1.Column))
                        Set rngTarget = wsTarget.Cells(rowOutputTarget, j)
                        rngTarget.Resize(n).Value2 = rngSrc.Value2
                    
                        If lastrow < rowOutputTarget + n Then
                            lastrow = rowOutputTarget + n
                        End If
                    
                    End If
                Next
            End With
    
            bookName.Range("A" & nameCount).Value = wbSource.Name
            'update output row  '2+12-1=13
             
            nameCount = nameCount + 1
            rowOutputTarget = lastrow
            
            'close the opened workbook
            wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
        'get the next file
        strFile = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Data imported.", vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
End Sub
```

Comment: This throws a Application defined or Object defined error 1004 on encountering the first blank column of second source file. It copy pastes data from first file well.

Comment: Error thrown is at the following line :  rngTarget.Resize(n).Value2 = rngSrc.Value2 where value of n is 0

Comment: @deepjaya Are do you mean a complete blank column between other columns (no header) or just a column with no data ?

Comment: Column with no data. This column was blank for first file as well but it did not throw any error then

Comment: @deepjaya Change line to `If n > 0 then rngTarget.Resize(n).Value2 = rngSrc.Value2`

Comment: Thanks for this code. It worked much much better than mine. The code is case sensitive in column names. premium @ 25% in source does not get captured in Premium column in target. Anyway to change that ?

Comment: @DeepJaya Change the option on the find `srcRow.Find(What:=Cr1, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False`